# Is it possible to monitor/track the connection pooling from WSO2 server

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

We have recently changed the ldap connection to secured for WSO2 EI 6.4.0 integration and broker profiles.
The following are the configurations made in user-mgmt.xml file.

```
<UserStoreManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager">
 <Property name="TenantManager">org.wso2.carbon.user.core.tenant.CommonHybridLDAPTenantManager</Property>
 <Property name="ConnectionURL">ldaps://{URL}:636 </Property>
   ...
  <Property name="ConnectionPoolingEnabled">true</Property>
```

wso2 integrator and broker profiles are configured as windows services using yajsw and so to enable connection pooling ,added a new configuration in wrapper.config file and restarted the service.

wrapper.java.additional.41 = -Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.protocol=ssl

However,IT team found that the number of connection is high and looks like connection pooling is not working.

Is it possible to monitor/track the ldaps traffic from WSO2 server ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to apply the connection pooling could you please try to add the following in the startup script (in the wrapper file)

`ldap.connect.pool.maxsize=20`